# Did Facebook Request 2.0 have daily limits pre user pre day?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

i have some confuse about the facebook Request2.0 system.

in app Apps->Insights->Diagnostics bottom said

Feature Limits-> Requests 1.0-> per user, per day->30

but does Request 2.0 have the same limits num?

i check some famous game , like Zynga's Mafia War2 they only let user to send FreeGift request to other user one time ,next time refresh the page even reload the game, can not send FreeGift request any more

so the feature that Zynga did for the request limits ,is prevent FreeGift to destroy the game balance or just facebook have some kind of policy ?

thanks